# Mysql on Mac: Changing datadir not working, re-initializatiing datadir not working as well

Tags: mysql, macos, permissions

I am very new to the Mysql/Database stuff, and I am currently running out of ideas. In addition, I am also a complete MAC noob (I did the same thing yesterday on a Win11 Machine, where it worked as described online, by adding a "network service" to the list of permissions).

My problem is easily described: I changed the datadir folder in the system settings under "MySQL". When I try to start the server (from the system settings), it won't start.

I found online (in this forum), that I have to grant permissions to the new folder. I did that using
`sudo chown -R _mysql path/of/my/new/data/folder`
`sudo chgrp -R _mysql path/of/my/new/data/folder`

Both commands seem to work, since path/of/my/new/data/folder has _mysql permissions when I check the folder information.

The problem is, it doesn't work. Changing back to the old datadir, it works again. I also tested a different path/of/another/new/data/folder (different folder). I conclude, it is something with the folders. However, normally the online guidance (at least what I can understand) ends here, because at this point it typically works for people.

Hopefully, someone here has an ideas that I can try.

Best regards, T.E.

I tried:

I found online (in this forum), that I have to grant permissions to the new folder. I did that using
`sudo chown -R _mysql path/of/my/new/data/folder`
`sudo chgrp -R _mysql path/of/my/new/data/folder`

Both commands seem to work, since path/of/my/new/data/folder has _mysql permissions when I check the folder information.

I am expecting:
Some small hint, where to look and how to find the problem.

### EDIT

Since I don't want to answer my question, because it would look like a solution, I edited it. I got some reply on the question as a comment already. Those are the first three comments from Bill Karwin.

I tried to follow [these instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html) to initialize a database on my MAC. Step by step:

1. went to directory `cd usr/local/mysql`
2. created mysql-files folder there (was not existing before, so I assume this is not really required) and gave it permissions `sudo chown mysql:mysql mysql-files` and `sudo chmod 750 mysql-files`, just to do the exact same steps as in the instructions
3. tried to initialize data directory with `sudo bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql` -> ERROR: `mysqld: Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysql-8.2.0-macos13-x86_64/data/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)`
4. deleted the 'data' folder, so that I can start over with the initialization using again `sudo bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql` -> worked (note, without `sudo` I got `Permission denied`)
5. went to the directory where I want the datadir to be `cd my/own/path` (changed the path here)
6. created mysql folder here `sudo mkdir mysql`
7. gave permissions `sudo chown mysql:mysql mysql` and `sudo chmod 750 mysql`
8. went back to mysql installation directory `cd usr/local/mysql`
9. initialized database with `sudo bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/my/own/path/mysql --datadir=/my/own/path/mysql/data`
10. got ERROR, see below

```
2023-11-05T12:21:50.544687Z 0 [System] [MY-015017] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - start.
2023-11-05T12:21:50.546782Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.2.0-macos13-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) initializing of server in progress as process 898
2023-11-05T12:21:50.546830Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010338] [Server] Cant find error-message file '/my/own/path/mysql/share/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
2023-11-05T12:21:50.548153Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /my/own/path/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2023-11-05T12:21:50.550008Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/my/own/path/mysql/data/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2023-11-05T12:21:50.550019Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /my/own/path/mysql/data/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-11-05T12:21:50.550085Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-05T12:21:50.550260Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.2.0-macos13-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.2.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-11-05T12:21:50.550554Z 0 [System] [MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.
```

At this point, I really don't know how to proceed, because this is, at least to me, exactly what the instructions require me to do. Maybe someone can see from the error message what is happening, or someone else had this issue in the past?

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards, T.E.

Comment: Here's a hint: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html

Comment: Hello, and thanks a lot for the hint!
First, I am sorry that the question seems uninformed, and gives the impression of a lack of research. That's not the impression I want to make. However, it reflects my knowledge at this point.
To the hint: I initialized the database after installation, and I have a working datadir in /usr/local/mysql/data. What is not working is the change to a custom one.
Do I understand that correctly, that I can (again) initialize a database, but in a custom directory, where MySQL takes care of the permissions for me in the process?
Thanks in advance, best regards!

Comment: If you change the datadir, you'll be using a datadir that isn't initialized. E.g. it has no data dictionary, no system database, no logs, etc. There are some baseline files that MySQL needs to be set up in the datadir (wherever it is) before it can start using that datadir. If you change the datadir, you've abandoned the old datadir, and you need to initialize the new one.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for taking the effort answering! To me that makes sense. I don't understand why on Win11 I don't have to do it though...
Anyways, I assume then that initializing a database is possible in different locations and I will try to do that (I thought initialization would always happen in /use/local/mysql/data). I will post the result here.
Question aside: The custom folder is an existing database created on a Win11 machine (I wonder why MySQL does not see the required files it needs there...), so will initializing the folder delete it? Best regards!

Comment: In the manual page I linked to: "the command that initializes the data directory does not overwrite any existing mysql schema tables, so it is safe to run in any circumstances." Note that the files are specific to the version of MySQL you use, so if you expect to use an initialized datadir from a prior version of MySQL, the result is unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks again for the hints! I will edit my initial question, since this needs a little more space. I will note which comments belonged to the initial question.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's completely okay on this site to post an answer to your own question. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: On my Macbook, the user and group created for MySQL is `_mysql` / `_mysql`.

Comment: On the MacBook I am currently working it is _mysql/_mysql as well. So this should not be the problem.
After hours googling I tried to switch to MongoDB (also because my research gave the impression that without properly using relational data structures, I don't need a relational database). Since I develop in Python, I thought this should match well. But it didn't, this time the Win11 machine made issues.
Therefore, I am back to relational now, this time SQLite. For my application SQLite is perfectly fine. SQLite works, since no server is required.

Answer (score 0):

I self-answer my question to make the final status visible to users googling the problem and finding this thread.

I could not find a way to properly set up a MySQL database on two development environments (Win11-PC and MacBook Pro) and get this to work. The initial plan was to have the `datadir` in a cloud folder and change the `datadir` on both environments to that folder, so that both environments share the same database. On my MacBook, the database was not accepting the new `datadir`. Re-initializating the database did not do the trick either.

I tried to change to MongoDB, which resulted in the Win11 Server to crash as soon as I changed the data directory of MongoDB to the cloud folder.

Eventually, I decided to use a simple SQLite database file, which works without a server. This works for me, since my application will not gather large amounts of data and relocating the database is rather easy by just copying a single file.

Thanks to Bill Karwin for answering and trying to help.

Best regards, TE